# Finding an element in an array C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm having troubles finding an element on an array.

I have a 2D array of elements    `t_elem **array`.

For the size of the array , I used the malloc function with  `#define SIZE_X 45`and `#define SIZE_Y 35`. Doesn't seem to be any problem with the malloc

The struct elem:

```
typedef struct elem
{

    int choice; 
    int color;

}t_elem;
```

`choice` is supposed to be a boolean : `1` if the element is choosen , `0` if it's not.

I initialize all the elements to `0` , except `array[3][17]` (3rd column and 17th line)

When I want to access to the choosen element , I use the following code:

```
array[3][17].choice = 1;  

while(array[i][j].choice != 1 && i < SIZE_X && j < SIZE_Y)
{
    i++;
    j++;
}
printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
```

I expect the `printf()` to return `3 17` , but all I got is `35 35`

I'm not that good in C and I may be missing something evident. Any help please?

Comment: Why don't you debug it?

Comment: ignoring other issues Your loop will never iterate element [3][17]. It only iterate [0][0], [1][1], [2][2]... [35][35] elements because You increase i and j simultaneously, so main loop is wrong to show [3][17]

Comment: You're right stupid mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're incrementing both `i` and `j` in every iteration. This will only give you elements like

```
array[0][0]
array[1][1]
array[2][2]
...
```

What you need here is a nested loop.

Sample pesudocode:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE_X; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE_Y; j++)    //for a particular value of i, traverse all values of j
    {
         if (array[i][j].choice == 1)
             printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
    }
```

Comment: As I said earlier that's a stupid mistake. I will try this thank you very much

Comment: @user4135594 You're welcome. BTW, i did not put that comment and wrote the answer beforehands, so the _As I said earlier_ is not applicable to me. :-)